# Magmi | Overwriting images with the same image name as the Original

Tags: magento, image-processing, magmi

It appears when updating attributes & images, Magmi checks to see if the value you’re entering matches that value that already exists. In the case of images, it checks only file name, no other statistic about the file (such as size). If the value is the same, it does not proceed with replacing it. I loaded a lot of images and made the mistake of not re-sizing them before hand. So I re-sized the same images but when I overwrite it, it seems to ignore it keeping the original image i loaded in Magento. Anybody have a work around for this or something I can have updated to overwrite the images? I would hate to have to go through and rename all these images.

Thanks in advance,

Jim Browning

Comment: Ended up using the batch rename in photoshop and reloaded the images.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?